# Xamarin Forms Android Anydpi-v26

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icons

I am trying to add an icon for my app, I added in every folder (*dpi) its corresponding image. but for devices with android api 26 or higher anydpi-v26 is used but it is not showing the icon correctly. My question is is there a way to prevent the use of anydpi-v26?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is is there a way to prevent the use of anydpi-v26?

An easy way is to delete it.

anydpi-v26: These resources take precedence in any dpi. If SDK/API level is 26 or higher, the resources will always be picked up from anydpi-v26 regardless of devices density

Comment: I tried that but there is something in the code (built in code) that uses it. I could not access it. but lets say I manage to remove the code that depends on this folder, then the *dpi folder will be used?

Comment: This should work. But i prefer to delete the folder.